# Scaling with a 4k monitor and 2k monitor

Tags: nvidia, multiple-monitors, display, 4k-monitor

I'm currently using two 2k monitors and a third 4k monitor.
Is there any way to use max resolution on all of them and scale things up a bit on just the 4k monitor? I've been digging around for ages but it seems the only option is to use Windows 10.

If it's not obvious - things look tiny on the 4k monitor, it's hard to read. And using 2k resolution on a 4k monitor looks terrible.

Comment: I really wish there was an answer to this. I'd love to take advantage for 4k but everything is too hard to read and scaling system fonts isn't good enough cause you have to then scale everything in each app.

Comment: I would love to know as I just bought a 4k monitor :O

Comment: Did you every try the answer posted below?

Answer (score 0):

Assume you are using x-window, ubuntu 18.04/18.10, gnome. An approach to your problem is: keep resolution of 4k monitor, raise your 2k monitors resolution to 4k and scale up all windows 200 %. Detail step as follows:

1. Connect all monitors
2. Go to setting > displays > set scale to 200% (global scaling)
3. Type xrandr to check for id of all monitors. Here I assume you have monitor 'HDMI-0' of 3840x2160, monitor 'HDMI-1' and 'HDMI-2' of 1920x1080. Now assume you want to place (left) 'HDMI-0'-'HDMI-1'-'HDMI-2' (right).
4. Run the following

> xrandr --dpi 276 --fb 11520x2160
>   --output HDMI-0 --mode 3840x2160 --pos 0x0
>   --output HDMI-1 --scale 2x2 --pos 3840x0 --panning 3840x2160+0+0
>   --output HDMI-2 --scale 2x2 --pos 7680x0 --panning 3840x2160+0+0

(Note: 11520=3840+1920x2+1920x2)